# How does Selenium Test class run in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have a question regarding Selenium web Driver. I want to test my web application using selenium. I write the test class in test folder of my maven project. once I give maven build command, The test classes are run,and after successful run of test classes,the build will be successful and I can deploy my app in web-apps folder of my apache-tomcat. But to run the test in Selenium I need to have my app already running in my localhost. How will this happen ?? Or is there something wrong with my approach??

Comment: what is issue? without maven your test not running?

Answer (score 0):

Starting and stopping of your server/application is not part of running your test classes. So you have to start your application before the test and shutdown after the test manually. So if you want to run your tests automatically you also have to start and stop your server and application automatically.

To do so:

- bind the start of your server/application to the pre-integration-test phase of the maven-lifecylce
- bind the selenium-plugin to the integration-test phase
- bind the shutdown of server/application to the post-integration-test phase of the maven-lifecycle

[Introduction to the Maven Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) gives you a good understanding of the different phases a build consists of.

Moreover I would recommend you not to run the tests against your localhost. Instead choose a machine - maybe a virtual host - that you can startup and shutdown as you need it.